# Critical points of $(x-y)(1-xy)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = (x-y)(1-xy)$

$\frac{df}{dx} = 1-2xy + y^2 = 0$

$2xy + y^2 = -1$

$x^2 - 2xy + y^2 = x^2 - 1$

$(y-x)^2 = x^2-1$

$y-x = \sqrt{x^2+1}$

$y = x + \sqrt{x^2+1}$

$\frac{df}{dy} = -1-x^2 + 2xy = 0$

$-x^2 + 2xy = 1$

$x(-x+2y) = 1$

$-x+2y = \frac{1}{x}$

$y = \frac{1+x²}{2x}$

$x + \sqrt{x^2+1} = \frac{1+x^2}{2x}$

Where did I mess up? By using wolfram It seems like the critical points should be $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ and they're both saddle as there is no maxima nor minima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add $f_x$ and $f_y$ you get

$$y^2-x^2=0.$$

There are four solutions: $1,1$; $1,-1$; $-1,1$ and $-1,-1$. But $-1,1$ and $1,-1$ do not work with $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$. So we are left with $1,1$ and $-1,-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x,y) = x-x^2y-y+xy^2\to f_x = 1-2xy+y^2 = 0 = f_y = -x^2-1+2xy\to y^2+1=2xy= x^2+1\to x^2=y^2\to x = \pm y$. Can you continue?